# After using @PostConstruct on initialize() my @Controller is not being registered

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, autowired

I am trying out a simple application using Springboot.

Here is my **Application.java** class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Autowired(required=true)
    private Listener listener;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        SQS sqs = new SQS();
        sqs.init();
        sqs.createQueue("myQueue");
        listener.run();
   }
}
```

And here is my **UserController.java**

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/findall", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getAll(@RequestParam(value = "status", required=false) String status, Model model) {
        Iterable<User> users = userDao.findAll();
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("findall");
        model.addAttribute("userobj",new User());
        mav.addObject("users", users);
        mav.addObject("status",status);
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping (value = "edit", method = RequestMethod.POST, params="action=ADD")
    {
    public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute UserDto userDto) {
        try {
            if(userDto.getId() != null) {   
                throw new UserExists();
            }

            SQS.sendMessage(userDto);
            return "redirect:findall?status=success";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error Saving User");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "redirect:findall?status=failure";
        }
    }
```

Now the issue is that my Controller does not get registered(i.e when I try hitting the URL I get page not found)when I use **@PostConstruct** on the initialize method.

When I try removing the **@PostConstruct** it works fine. But I need the initialize() to run() the listener (Another runnable class that I have written for reading message from the Queue)

I tried tweaking the Application class where I would not require **@PostConstruct** but it did not work.

Here was what I tried to do with **Application.java** class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Autowired(required=true)
    private static Listener listener;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        initialize();
    }

    public static void initialize() {
        SQS sqs = new SQS();
        sqs.init();
        sqs.createQueue("myQueue");
        listener.run();
   }
}
```

In this case the **@Controller works fine**. **But** the **@Autowiring** of **private static Listener listener;** fails and throws NullPointerException.

So could anyone tell me a workaround this so that both of the below work.

1. @Autowired(required=true)
   private Listener listener; --> gets autowired so I will be able to run() it
2. My Controller API's are registered so that I can hit the URL's

Comment: You cannot autowire a static field so yes that will fail. I suggest using the Spring Integration AWS support to have better spring support instead of working out your own. Non the less the latter should work, however I think that your `run` method blocks proper startup of your application making it appear as if your controller doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Spring Cloud AWS library and register SQS endpoint listener with the following annotation:

```
@SqsListener("${cloud.aws.sqs.queue.name}")
```

I recommend to create a separate @Component class for this SQS listener, the main Application class is not proper place for such thing.

Here is [Spring Cloud AWS guide](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_annotation_driven_listener_endpoints)

Comment: I do have a separate component class for the SQS listener called as Listener. I will try the library you mentioned. For **queue.name** should I be using my own queue name?